# why do I need "static" for a char array in the function?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    

char* test_static_char(int n);

int main()
{    
    printf("calling through 1: %s \n", test_static_char(1));    
    printf("calling through 2: %s \n", test_static_char(2));    
    printf("calling through 3: %s \n", test_static_char(3));

    return 0;
}

char* test_static_char(int n)
{        
    static char test_char[4];    
    test_char[0] = '\0';

    switch(n)
    {
        case 1: strcat(test_char,"A");
                strcat(test_char,"B");
                strcat(test_char,"C");
                break;


         case 2: strcat(test_char,"D");
                 strcat(test_char,"E");
                 strcat(test_char,"F");
                 break;

         default: strcat(test_char,"G");
                  strcat(test_char,"H");
                  strcat(test_char,"I");    
    }    

    return test_char;    
}
```

---

I get the desired result only when I add "static" to the char array.
But I don't know why. I think it should work as I expect without "static" because 
 , everytime the function is called, test_char[4] is used as if it had never been used before. In addition, I get this warning message when I don't use static
, "fuction returns address of local variable"

```
<The desired result>
calling through 1: ABC

calling through 2: DEF

calling through 3: GHI
```

Comment: `static` inside a function means the variable will keep its state between function calls.

Comment: I know what "static" does. But it seems needless in this code. why does test_char[4] have to keep its state every time the function in which test_char[4] resides is called? I think all the function calls in the main are independent of each other.

Comment: No, the function calls are not independent...they all call the `test_static_char(int n)` function and `static test_char[4]` will have the same state always. Your problem is that your function will return address to a local variable. If you want to fix it so it does not need `static` change it to
`char* test_char = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);`

Then you have to take care of freeing the allocated memory. Your code is a bad design. You have to allocate the buffer `test_char` int the main and pass it to the function as an argument for multiple uses.

Comment: e.g. setup your function like this `char* test_static_char(char* buffer, int n)` or `void test_static_char(char* buffer, int n)` and create the buffer as a global variable in your source code.